# How to generate and manage symetric cryptographic keys with GPG and SKS?

Tags: key-management, aes

I work on people and companies databases requiring high confidentiality.
Input data (mostly clear XML files) is loaded into an Oracle database, and sensitive columns are encrypted using AES265 algorithm (performance is required).

This is quite easy to do, using Oracle dbms_crypto package, and providing any 32 bytes string as a key.

Now, data is transferred to other systems for analysis purposes, which may require some sensitive data to be de-crypted. They need to access the same key, of course.

I think of using GPG for generating strong symmetric keys, and SKS for making the keys available to remote systems.

Searching around, I could not answer these 2 questions :

1. How to generate a symmetric key with GPG, and manipulate it outside
   GPG ?
2. Can SKS store symmetric keys ?